# Angular12 - intercepting graphql HTTP request and responses

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, graphql

So, we've got Graphql response handler

```
export const handleResponse = (operation: DocumentNode): OperatorFunction<any, any> => {
  return pipe(
    map((response: any) => {
      const definition = operation.definitions[0] as OperationDefinitionNode;
      const selection = definition.selectionSet.selections[0] as FieldNode;
      const selectionName = selection.name.value ?? null;
      if (!selectionName) {
        throw new Error(`${selection.kind} name must be present.`);
      }
      if (response.data[selectionName]?.errors) {
        handleError(response.data[selectionName].errors);
      }
      return response.data[selectionName];
    }),
  );
};

const handleError = (errors: string[]) => {
  if (Array.isArray(errors) && errors.length) {
    const errorArrayToString = errors.map(error => JSON.stringify(error)).toString();
    throw new Error(errorArrayToString);
  }
};
```

It does works pretty well, but I also want to use notification service. I want to do something like that

```
const handleError = (errors: string[]) => {
  if (Array.isArray(errors) && errors.length) {

    notificationsService.show('Any error message')

    const errorArrayToString = errors.map(error => JSON.stringify(error)).toString();
    throw new Error(errorArrayToString);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, but I decided to move this logic into HTTP interceptor. Here is the code

```
@Injectable()
export class ApolloErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private _notificationsService: TuiNotificationsService) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      tap((response: any) => {
        if (request.body?.operationName) {
          const operationName = request.body.operationName;

          if (response.body?.data[operationName]?.errors) {
            response.body.data[operationName].errors.forEach((error: any) => {
              this._notificationsService
                .show(error.message, { status: TuiNotification.Error, autoClose: 5000 })
                .subscribe();
            });
          }
        }
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

It will intercept only those responses that have an "operationName" in the body, which is Graphql responses

But now you need to explicitly make sure to specify the name of the request

[query example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7PkR.png)
and
[mutation example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gasym.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject the service inside a variable

```
import { Component, Injector, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NotificationsService } from './custom.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  // @Constructor services injectors

  notificationsService: NotificationsService;

  /**
   * Constructor
  */
  constructor(
    private _injector: Injector
  ) {
    this.notificationsService = this._injector.get<NotificationsService>(NotificationsService);
}

 ngOnInit(): void {
 }

 //custom error handler
 handleError (errors: string[]) => {
  if (Array.isArray(errors) && errors.length) {

    this.notificationsService.show('Any error message')

    const errorArrayToString = errors.map(error => JSON.stringify(error)).toString();
    throw new Error(errorArrayToString);
  }
};
}
```